# Custom datepicker theme not applying

Tags: css, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm trying to enable a custom datepicker theme to my site. Right now I can only get the jquery-ui.css themes to work, but they look aweful, and I don't want to create a new myself.

I visited this site: [jQuery datepicker skins](http://rtsinani.github.io/jquery-datepicker-skins/)

Have downloaded the css file which I should need, but nothing happens. On the github site [Git site for custom datepicker](https://github.com/rtsinani/jquery-datepicker-skins) they say you have to add the appropriated classes to your datepickers, but don't know what that means.

This is what I load to get it to work:

```
<!-- Jquery Ui script -->
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<!-- Datepicker themes -->
<link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- Datepicker melon theme -->
<link href="~/Content/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

If i delete the jquery-ui.css file, the datepicker just shows without any theme.

Comment: Check this example- https://github.com/rtsinani/jquery-datepicker-skins/blob/master/input.html

Comment: Thanks.. i see what i missed.. didn't see that file you refering to.. weird.

Answer (score 4):

Fixed the problem with Rahul comment.

Added this line:

```
.datepicker('widget').wrap('<div class="ll-skin-melon"/>');
```

after the datepickers.

**Preview:**

```
//Initialize datepickers
    $("#departureDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        inline: true,

    })
    $("#returnDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        inline: true,
    })
    .datepicker('widget').wrap('<div class="ll-skin-melon"/>');
```